# В Internet Explorer подменю при наведении прячется за контент

Tags: jquery, html

Проблема такая: у меня два блока, один содержит нав. меню с сайта softanaka, а второй контент страницы. На первом навешан jquery скрипт, показывающий подменю при наведении мышкой. Во всех браузерах, кроме Internet Explorer все нормально работает и меню перекрывает весь контент. А вот в Internet Explorer это подменю при наведении прячется за контентную часть страницы. Заранее всех благодарю.

Comment: Свойство z-index не знакомо? И вообще скиньте Ваш код - поколдуем)

Comment: Проблема в вашем css, jquery тут не причем...

Comment: про jquery я просто сказал иногда стиль не работающий в css работает в стилях заданных с jquery 
а код не нужен там 2 <div> 
в первом меню второй содержит основную часть

Comment: Если хочешь получить быстрое и правильное решение выкладывай свой код. Рекомендую пользоваться сайтом [jsfiddle.net][1].


  [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй z-index задать

Comment: z-index работает везде кроме IE 
без z-index работает только если задать позицию absolute 
но в этом случае при увеличении страницы блок меняет позицию вправо относительно основного блока и не увеличивается вместе с другими блоками а копаться не хочется ведь все равно в explorer блок прячется
может знаете чем заменить этот z-index в отдельном css для него

Comment: мне кажется нужно играться с zoom:1 xD

 (еще раз спасиба Билл за твое "детище")

Comment: а что это за zoom:1 xD??

Comment: Так вы еще не знакомы с [IE haslayout](http://html-css.info/2009/07/haslayout-ie/)?.. :trollface:

Кстати - разрабы IE даже на офф сайте толком не смогли обьяснить как оно работает :D.

Ну да тут ничего не поделаешь, как говорится в семье не без урода

Comment: Я бы сказал в IE не без урода...
На счет hasLayout нормальное описание на htmlbook есть. Но все равно понять его сложновато.

Comment: и начинать - бессмислено, IE7 скоро умрет

Comment: какой IE 7 ? у меня на  IE та же самая фигня не работает z-index

Comment: еще один неверующий в doctype? :D

Comment: какой IE 7 ? у меня на IE 8 та же самая фигня не работает z-index

Comment: а насчет zoom показывает что он есть и что он zoom:1 но результата нет(((

Comment: Про HasLayout можно прочитать статью 2005 года на msdn.microsoft.com, только на английском. Вот [ссылка][1].

Недавно была такая же проблема в IE. Решилась установкой z-index.


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250481%28VS.85%29.aspx